# Remove duplicates when interval considers end and start time the same

Tags: google-bigquery

[image]

**It looks like Chrome does not display the tables but it works fine on Edge**

For some reason, I get a duplicate when `end_at` has the same value as `time`.

The query used:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
TIME(hour, 0, 0) AS time,
date, 
start_at,
end_at,
total 
FROM a, UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(0, 23)) hour 
WHERE hour BETWEEN EXTRACT(hour FROM TIME(start_at)) AND EXTRACT(hour FROM TIME(end_at)) 
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Duplicates seems to be occurred because `BETWEEN` operator is inclusive.

In your case, 3rd row with '`22`:53:37' in `start_at` and '`23`:00:00' in `end_at` will be expanded into two rows by cross-joining with `hour` with key `22` and `23`, and will make duplication.

Consider below instead of using `BETWEEN` operator

```sql
 WHERE TIME(hour, 0, 0) >= TIME_TRUNC(start_at, HOUR) AND TIME(hour, 0, 0) < end_at
```

Note: assuming `start_at` column and `end_at` column are `TIME` data type.

Above condition generates below output:

[image]